# How to print a Trie in Java?

Tags: java, printing, trie

I have a trie implementation and I want to print my trie out so I can see what's in it. Preferable in a depth first traversal so the words actually make sense. Here is my code:

```
package trie;

public class Trie {
    public TrieNode root;

    public Trie(){
        root = new TrieNode();
    }

    /*
    public Trie(char c){
        TrieNode t = new TrieNode(c);
        root = t;
    }*/

    public void insert(String s, int phraseNb){
        int i = 0;
        TrieNode node = root;
        char[] string = s.toCharArray();
        TrieNode child = null;

        while(i < string.length){
            child = node.getChild(string[i]);
            if(child == null){
                child = new TrieNode(string[i]);
                node.addChild(child);
            }
            else{
                node = child;
            }
            i++;
        }

        node.endOfWord();
        node.setNb(phraseNb);
    }

    public int[] search(char[] c){
        TrieNode node = root;
        for(int i = 0; i < c.length-1; i++){
            node = root;
            int s = 0;
            while(i+s < c.length){
                TrieNode child = node.getChild(c[i + s]);
                if(child == null){
                    break;
                }
                if(child.isWord()){
                    return new int[] {i, s+1, node.getNb()};
                }
                node = child;
                s++;
            }
        }
        return new int[] {-1, -1, -1};
    }

    public void print(){

    }
}

package trie;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TrieNode {
    private boolean endOfWord;
    private int phraseNb;
    private char letter;
    private HashSet<TrieNode> children = new HashSet<TrieNode>();

    public TrieNode(){}

    public TrieNode(char letter){
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public boolean isWord(){
        return endOfWord;
    }

    public void setNb(int nb){
        phraseNb = nb;
    }

    public int getNb(){
        return phraseNb;
    }

    public char getLetter(){
        return letter;
    }

    public TrieNode getChild(char c){
        for(TrieNode child: children){
            if(c == child.getLetter()){
                return child;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Set<TrieNode> getChildren(){
        return children;
    }

    public boolean addChild(TrieNode t){
        return children.add(t);
    }

    public void endOfWord(){
        endOfWord = true;
    }

    public void notEndOfWord(){
        endOfWord = false;
    }
}
```

Just an explanation as to how to go about doing it or some pseudo code is all I need. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you familiar with depth first traversals? This is more of a question about formatting than implementation.

Comment: I understand what it is but do not understand fully how to do within a trie

Comment: Hint: use generics - you'll be able to reuse this code later.

Answer (score 2):

This is the full example of Trie Implementation using HashMap.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

class TrieNode{

    private char c;
    private Map<Character,TrieNode> children = new HashMap<>();
    private boolean isLeaf = false;

    TrieNode(){

    }

    /**
     * @param c the c to set
     */
    public void setC(char c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    /**
     * @return the children
     */
    public Map<Character, TrieNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    /**
     * @return the isLeaf
     */
    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return isLeaf;
    }

    /**
     * @return the c
     */
    public char getC() {
        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @param isLeaf the isLeaf to set
     */
    public void setLeaf(boolean isLeaf) {
        this.isLeaf = isLeaf;
    }
}

class Trie{

    TrieNode rootNode;

    public Trie(){
        rootNode = new TrieNode();
    }

    public void insertWord(String word){
        TrieNode current = rootNode;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char c = word.charAt(i);
            Map<Character,TrieNode> children = current.getChildren();
            if(children.containsKey(c)){
                current = children.get(c);
            }
            else{
                TrieNode trieNode = new TrieNode();
                children.put(c, trieNode);
                current = children.get(c);
            }
        }
        current.setLeaf(true);
    }

    public boolean searchWord(String word){
        TrieNode current = rootNode;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            Map<Character,TrieNode> children = current.getChildren();
            char c = word.charAt(i);
            if(children.containsKey(c)){
                current = children.get(c);
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        if(current.isLeaf() && current!=null){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void print(TrieNode rootNode,int level, StringBuilder sequence) {
        if(rootNode.isLeaf()){
            sequence = sequence.insert(level, rootNode.getC());
            System.out.println(sequence);
        }

        Map<Character, TrieNode> children = rootNode.getChildren();
        Iterator<Character> iterator = children.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            char character = iterator.next();
            sequence = sequence.insert(level, character); 
            print(children.get(character), level+1, sequence);
            sequence.deleteCharAt(level);
        }
    }
}

class TrieImplementation{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Trie trie = new Trie();
        trie.insertWord("Done");
        trie.insertWord("Dont");
        trie.insertWord("Donor");
        trie.insertWord("Sanjay");
        trie.insertWord("Ravi");
        trie.insertWord("RaviRaj");
        TrieNode root = trie.rootNode;
        trie.print(root,0,new StringBuilder(""));
        System.out.println(trie.searchWord("Dont"));
        System.out.println(trie.searchWord("Donor"));
        System.out.println(trie.searchWord("Jay"));
        System.out.println(trie.searchWord("Saviraj"));
        System.out.println(trie.searchWord("RaviRaj"));
        System.out.println(trie.searchWord("Aaviraj"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I remember my university times when I tried to print the tree on console. Trie is the same in terms of printing IMO... This is what I did and this is what I suggest you to do as well:
Take some paper and draw your trie there.
Now think how would you like to print the trie.
I think trie is composed like N-tree (not a binary but a tree that has a lot of children). Besides that its a recursive structure just like a tree.
So you really can apply here the depth first approach.

Lets assume you want to print a trie like this (node 'a' is a root):

> a

```
  b

     e

     f

     g
  d
```

this is like a trie that contains words:
ad
abe
abf
abg

So you start with a root, accumulate the offset and traverse recursively:

```
printTrie(Node node, int offset) {
     print(node, offset)
     // here you can play with the order of the children
     for(Node child : node.getChildren()) {
          printTrie(child, offset + 2)
     } 
}
```

Start your recursion with:

```
printTrie(root, 0)
```

And you'll be done

I've used 2 as a constant to play with the offset change coefficient, change it to 3,4 or whatever and see what happens.

Hope this helps.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The [visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) design pattern is often useful when dealing with composite data structures like Trie. It enables a developer to decouple the traversal of the composite data structure from the information retrieved at each node.

One could use the visitor design pattern to print the Trie.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
public void printTrie(TrieNode node,String s) {
    String strSoFar = s;
    strSoFar += String.valueOf(node.c);
    if(node.isLeaf)
    {
        System.out.println(strSoFar);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Stack<TrieNode> stack = new Stack<TrieNode>();
        Iterator<TrieNode> itr = node.children.values().iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            stack.add(itr.next());
        }
        while(!stack.empty()){
            TrieNode t = stack.pop();
            printTrie(t,strSoFar);
        }

    }
}
```

Try to call the function ,

```
trieObject.printTrie(trieObject.getRoot(), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example that I just threw together. Not the pretties printing and can only print the Trie once but it gets the job done. Hope it helps.

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class Trie
    {
      static TrieNode root = new TrieNode();
      static char endMarker = '?';
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        System.out.println(checkPresentsAndAdd("test"));
        System.out.println(checkPresentsAndAdd("taser"));
        System.out.println(checkPresentsAndAdd("tester"));
        System.out.println(checkPresentsAndAdd("tasters"));
        System.out.println(checkPresentsAndAdd("test"));
        System.out.println(checkPresentsAndAdd("tester"));

        printTrie(root);
      }

      public static boolean checkPresentsAndAdd(String word)
      {
        TrieNode node = root;
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
          char c = word.charAt(i);
          if(node.checkIfNeighbor(c))
          {
              node = node.getNeighbor(c);
          }
          else
          {
            node.addNeighbor(c);
            node = node.getNeighbor(c);
          }
        }

        boolean nord = false;
        if(!node.checkIfNeighbor(endMarker))
        {
          nord = true;
          node.addNeighbor(endMarker);
        }

        return nord;
      }

      public static void printTrie(TrieNode node)
      {

        if(node == null || node.visited)
            return;

        LinkedList<TrieNode> q = new LinkedList<TrieNode>();

        System.out.println(node);
        node.visited = true;
        q.add(node);

        while (!q.isEmpty())
        {
            TrieNode x = q.removeFirst();
            for(Map.Entry<Character,TrieNode> i : x.neighbors.entrySet())
            {
                if(i.getValue().visited == false)
                {
                   System.out.println(i);
                   i.getValue().visited = true;
                   q.add(i.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }

    class TrieNode
    {
      Map<Character, TrieNode> neighbors = new HashMap<Character, TrieNode>();

      boolean visited = false;
      public TrieNode(){}

      public boolean checkIfNeighbor(char c)
      {
        return neighbors.containsKey(c);
      }

      public TrieNode getNeighbor(char c)
      {
        if(checkIfNeighbor(c))
        {
          return neighbors.get(c);
        }

        return null;
      }

      public void addNeighbor(char c)
      {
        TrieNode node = new TrieNode();
        neighbors.put(c, node);
      }

      public String toString()
      {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Node:[neighbors: ");
        sb.append(neighbors);
        sb.append("]\n");

        return sb.toString();
      }
    }
```